# How can I map employees with schedules in Many-To-Many (or One-To-Many) Relationships with Spring Boot JPA

Tags: java, spring-boot, jpa

I can't find a way to map some entities with my SQL tables. I have an EMPLOYEES table (with PK employee_id), a DAYS_OF_WEEK table (with PK day_of_week_id), and an EMPLOYEES_SCHEDULES table (with composite PK of employee_id, day_of_week_id, and start_time, being the first two attributes FK to the said tables, and end_time being the only non-PK attribute).

```
EMPLOYEES
PK  employee_id
    role_id     FK

DAYS_OF_WEEK
PK  day_of_week_id
    name

EMPLOYEES_SCHEDULES
PK | employee_id    FK
   | day_of_week_id FK
   | start_time
     end_time
```

The class diagram that I have to follows says an Employee has 0 or many EmployeeSchedule objects associated, and that an EmployeeSchedule has 1 or many DayOfWeek objects associated. So, the classes in Java should look like this:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "EMPLOYEES")
public class Employee {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "employee_id")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int employeeId;

    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "role_id", referencedColumnName = "role_id")
    private Role role;
    
    // I don't know how to map this
    private List<EmployeeSchedule> employeeSchedule;
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "EMPLOYEES_SCHEDULES")
public class EmployeeSchedule {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "start_time")
    private LocalDate startTime;

    @Basic
    @Column(name = "end_time")
    private LocalDate endTime;
    
    // I don't know how to map this
    private List<DayOfWeek> dayOfWeek;
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "DAYS_OF_WEEK")
public class DayOfWeek {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "day_of_week_id")
    private byte dayId;

    @Basic
    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;
}
```

I know DayOfWeek could probably be replaced with an enum, but that's not the point of this post. If possible, please don't suggest changing the structure of the class diagram, because I have to use it strictly (nor should the relationships be bidirectional). But are the tables I made enough for mapping the classes? If so, how can I map them?

Answer (score 1):

You add something like this:

```
 @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "employeeSchedule")
private List<DayOfWeek> dayOfWeek=new ArrayList<>();
```

to your List of days.
Then you add atribute in entity DayOfWeek as:

```
    @JoinColumn(name = "NAME_OF_COLUMN", referencedColumnName = "NAME_OF_REFRENECED_COLUMN")
    @ManyToOne(optional = false)
    private EmployeeSchedule employeeSchedule=new ArrayList<>();
```

Note that name of atribute in entity DayOfWeek needs to be same as definition of "mappedBy" in entity EmployeeSchedule. Also, you need to intialize list.
I now noticed that you have same question for Employee entity.
So as described, you must add annotation to list. As there is no ZeroToMany annotation you use OneToMany beacuse this **annotation describes connection beetwen entitity classes,** not database. You can't connect 0 entities to many entities. So next annotation describes your connectin between tables.
Adding this to list:

```
 @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "employee")
private List<EmployeeSchedule> employeeSchedule=new ArrayList<>();
```

And adding this to Employee entity:

```
@JoinColumn(name = "NAME_OF_COLUMN", referencedColumnName = "NAME_OF_REFRENECED_COLUMN")
@ManyToOne(optional = false)
private Employee employee;
```

Comment: I think I did what you said but I'm having this error:
Unable to find column with logical name: day_of_week_id in org.hibernate.mapping.Table(employees_schedules) and its related supertables and secondary tables
Is it because they have the same name in both tables?

Comment: Definitely not, I always worked with same named columns(primary and foreign key) and didn't have any problems.  Are you sure this is the name of column in database table? It's hard to try guessing like this what it may be.  I don't know which database you use, but check for CAPS.

Comment: It is. If it wasn't, IntelliJ would tell me. I will see what else I can do, thanks for helping!

Comment: I know what happened. I'm actually looking in explanation and database, and one thing strucks me. If  in table EmployeeSchedule you have complex primaryKey with values of dayOfWeak, employee and startTime, how can one @Entity EmployeeSchedule have more? Also the excpetion explains that in your Entity beans there is no attribute that is related to column in database

Comment: You mean how can an employee tuple have more than one tuple linked in employees_shededules? Because of the composite key, two different employees can start working at the same hour and day. I think the table structure works, what would you change from it?

Comment: If something is primary key, it must be unique. That said, if you have complex primary key  made of employee_id, day_of_week_id and start time it naturally means that one set of this values must be unique. So i don't get how can you have collection of days_of_week in entity Employee_schedule that defines entity in table. At least it will be single object.  If one Employee schedule can have more days of week defined in database, then the database must change. Employee schedule then can't have variable days of week.  This is from perspective that you eant to use collection in entity bean.

Comment: In normal, you can make database like this. If you must not use enum for days of week and if Employee_schedule has more day_of_week objects, you need to add one more table in database which has complex primary key made of day_of_week_id and employee_schedule_id so you can have List of day_of_week in Employee_schedule entity

Comment: Thanks for the advice on creating another table. I'll update the post if I get it to work.

Comment: From what I understood, the @Table of EmployeeSchedule should not be a very complex table, but rather a simpler one with just start_time and end_time, and maybe an id to make things easier, and that simpler table should be referenced by a table that links the start and end times with the day of the week in order for me to make a DayOfWeek list attribute.